# FaxComexlib Operation Failed when sending fax

Tags: c#, fax

i am working on a faxing project

it work on my machine very well but when i deploy it on another machine

i get operation failed in FaxServer.ConnectedSubmit() ;

i found this link :

http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/faxcomexlib/operation-failed

bout i cannot find error code of my program COMException .

can any body guide me ?

Answer (score 2):

i resolve my problem and i will to share its answer  :

faxcomexlib need programs to open file extension ....

for example if we want send *.PDF file we need to install Acrobat Reader or For *.TXT file we

must set notepad to default text editor (NOT Notepad++)

if your machine has not program to open this files program throw this exception

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you locate your fax file to be sent that you can open it with the proper program by double clicking and that you don't see any pop ups or questions (such as "Set this program as default...").

#### Note on PDF files:

Even though I was able to open the PDF cleanly with Microsoft Edge I was not able to send the fax until I installed Adobe Reader, set it as the default program and made sure there were no additional pop ups.

Comment: Is there any way to send tiff file?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the error when installing with Server Manager the feature Desktop Experience.

Windows Picture and Fax Viewer is not included with Server 2008 R2, and cannot be downloaded/installed separately.  Windows Photo Viewer is included with 2008 R2 and may meet your needs.  You need to install the Desktop Experience feature using Server Manager.