# Unable to send fax through Fax Modem in Windows 10 Pro vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fax, winfax

While sending fax throught the application in vb.net giving the below error on the line (Dim sFaxJobIds() As String = oFaxDoc.ConnectedSubmit(oFaxSvr)). Can someone please help us here.

**Error** : Operation failed

**Code:**

```
Dim oFaxSvrType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("FaxcomEx.FaxServer")
Dim oFaxSvr As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(oFaxSvrType)
Dim oFaxDocType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("FaxcomEx.FaxDocument")

Dim sFaxServerName As String

Try

    'get name of this computer, we need this for the FaxServer object below 
    sFaxServerName = Environment.MachineName.Trim

    oFaxSvr.Connect(sFaxServerName)

    'run The routine for each Fax Data

    Dim oFaxDoc As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(oFaxDocType)
    With oFaxDoc
        .Sender.FaxNumber = oFD.SenderOfficePhone
        .Body = oFD.DocumentPath

        If oFD.CoverPageName <> vbNullString Then
            .Coverpage = oFD.CoverPageName
        End If

        If oFD.SenderName <> vbNullString Then
            .Sender.Name = oFD.SenderName
        End If

        If oFD.SenderOfficePhone <> vbNullString Then
            .Sender.OfficePhone = oFD.SenderOfficePhone
        End If

        If oFD.FaxNumber <> "" Then
            If oFD.RecipientName <> "" Then
                .Recipients.add(oFD.FaxNumber, oFD.RecipientName)
            Else
                .Recipients.add(oFD.FaxNumber)
            End If
        End If

    End With

    Dim sFaxJobIds() As String = oFaxDoc.ConnectedSubmit(oFaxSvr)
    oFaxDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360404/faxcomexlib-operation-failed-when-sending-fax